# This device does not support AR - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, augmented-reality

I'm trying to implement in a Flutter application to use the AR plugin. After running the app in a physical device. I get the following error:

[image]

I am facing issue with AR in my device, even if I install Google AR services.

Comment: does your device support AR? What device you're testing on? You can check if your device is in the supported devices list @ https://developers.google.com/ar/devices

Comment: Yeah i'm testing on realme c11, also infinix 10, and both doesn't exist on the list. Thaanks